# Observe fields on a form and report changes

Tags: javascript, observer-pattern

Observe fields on a form and report changes

I have now written a simple utility (part of the observer pattern) to observe the changes made in each field of a form.

```
var idInt = setInterval(function() {
  // each input is a document.getElementById(id)
  var len = inputList.lenght;

  while(len--) {
    //send value to somewhere
    someWhere(ininputList[len].value);
  }
}, 40)
```

but i have issues like:

1. when change the value with mouse (cut/paste)
2. when change the value programmatically

the value take by `someWhere(ininputList[len].value);` dont refresh even I tried to add events (onchange, oncut, onpaste, oninput, onkeyup) to the elements to avoid setIntervalloop but with the events when i try to change programmatically the values dont fires.

which would be a better approach to observe changes in the values ​​of elements (input [button | text | password | url | email], radio, checkbox, select) taking into account that programmatic changes monitorizen and changes through the interface user,

Note: I am looking for a raw solution, no jquery, prototype, js class or any framework just native javascript

Comment: why can't you bind to `change` event? -- `input.addEventListener('change', myFunction, false)` ?

Comment: I need real-time changes not when the user changes the field

Comment: also need to be triggered when change is done in a programmatic

Comment: So are you saying even when you have changed values in inputs your periodically called function sees old values?

Comment: no i need the new values

Comment: If the value of the form input has changed or been changed, those events will fire.  It doesn't matter how the values were updated.  Are you sure everything is bound correctly?

Comment: if the value is change like this `document.getElemetById('element').value = "newValue"` the event is fired too?

Comment: Nono, you are right, sorry.  However, out of curiosity, why is it the code that sets the value does not fire the change event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what is the problem because below code works

```
setInterval(function() {
  var inputList = document.getElementsByTagName('input')
  var len = inputList.length;

  while(len--) {
    console.log(inputList[len].value);
  }
}, 4000)​
```

It prints changed values every 4 secs, you can see it in action here http://jsfiddle.net/QKqzT/

Comment: is curious. I did an implementation where I have a model and there several elements (form, parafos, etc) were reported everything is based on the observer and a pubsub that notified the interested elements in the model